# Getting issue while building jitsiMeet SDK 2.11.0 on xcode 12.2

Tags: swift, sdk, xcode12, jitsi, jitsi-meet

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/ankitk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jitsi-meet-cusczvnrhzsgysadgutjwvwofufz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/JitsiMeet/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/JitsiMeetSDK.framework/JitsiMeetSDK normal
(1 failure)

I am using xcode 12.2 .Tried cleaning the DerivedData also but failed everytime.

Comment: how you fixed this problem

Comment: try given below link for solution provided.This might solve your problem.                              https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/8291